# VBA Copy and Paste

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        rng.Copy Destination:=wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1:D30")
```

How can I use `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` with the above code?

Comment: did you try recording a macro to get the syntax?

Comment: You are mixing two statements. `Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add` creates a new empty workbook. `rng.Copy Destination:=wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1:D30")` copies the contents of `rng` to the specified destination.  `Copy` is the VBA equivalent of Copy and Paste which you do not need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the rng variable defined and assigned properly, you can do:

```
Rng.Copy
wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1:D30").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

It needs to be in two separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
wbNew = Workbooks.Add  
rng.Copy  
wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1:D30").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```